# Как правильно хранить данные в бд с выводом в транслите

Tags: php, mysql

Как правильно хранить данные в базе данных и потом вывести их.
Например, вводим в адресную строку site.ru/kazan и открывается страница с информацию Казань. Как правильно в бд хранить название, kazan или Казань(Енг или Рус). Пробовал простой транслит, но он не справляется с мягкими знаками.
Можно сделать в бд 2 поля, name_eng и name_rus, когда вводишь в адресную строку название на енг он делает поиск и выводит поле рус. Есть по проще вариант, без создания доп поля?

Comment: Возьмите любой из методов обратимой транслитерации (скажем, по ГОСТ 7.79-2000, табл. 4-5) да запрограммируйте...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый правильный вариант – с двумя полями.
При сохранении новой записи в БД выполняете транслитерацию и сохраняете транслитерированный вариант в свое отдельное поле. Таким образом у вас будет один однозначный вариант соответствия адресной строки соответствующей странице. Плюс, поле с транслитом в БД нужно сделать индексируемым (уникальным) - это позволит быстро открывать любую страницу, даже если их будут сотни тысяч.

Answer (score 1):

я вижу два варианта

1) два поля: name_rus, name_trans

`WHERE (name_rus LIKE '%' $find '%' OR name_trans LIKE '%' $find '%')`

2) одно поле name написать функцию преобразования в транслит и делать поиск

`WHERE (name LIKE '%' $find '%' OR name LIKE '%' to_translit($find) '%')`

этот синтаксис работать не будет, я просто стараюсь передать суть

п.с. идеального решения не существует, у каждого решения будут плюсы и минусы